# How to wrap whole row to React Router Link in antd

Tags: react-router, antd

I have a table and need **wrap every table row to Link**. How can I do that? I need that when I click on the row I go to another route. I’ve already figured out how to make a link every cell, but with the whole row I don’t know how to make

```
const AccountList = props => {

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Acc",
      dataIndex: "fullName",
      key: "fullName",
      width: 170,
    },
    {
      title: "Number",
      dataIndex: "ID",
      key: "ID",
      width: 100
    },

  ];

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "15px" }}>
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={accInfoProps}
        pagination={false}
        size={"small"}
        title={() => <h2 style={{ float: "left" }}>Список аккаунтов</h2>}
        onRow={(record) => {
          return {
            onClick: () => {
              console.log(record.id)
            },
          };
        }}
      />
      ,
      <Pagination
        onChange={onChange}
        style={{ float: "right", marginTop: "15px" }}
        defaultCurrent={1}
        total={500}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AccountList;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `onRow` event handler on `Table` component to route to desired link `onClick`. If using `react-router-dom`, you can use the `Redirect` component to navigate to the new link.

```
<Table
  onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
    return {
      onClick: event => <Redirect push to={record.link}/>
    };
  }}
```